# Imported function can print value of variable without the variable being imported but i can't, why does this happen?

Tags: python

I have recently tried experimenting with importing files, this time I imported a function and I dont understand how the function can print the variable x's value but if I try to print x an error happens, can you explain why?

First.py

```
x=5
def a():
    print(x)
```

Second.py

```
from First import a
a()
print(x)

>>>5
>>>NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

I thought that either:
a() and print(x) both wouldn't work because I didn't import x as well
or that they would both work because variables inside a() would also be imported, I didn't expect this though

Comment: This is because `a` knows of `x` from the imported namespace. But you didn't import `x` into the current namespace, so you can't access it. To fix this, `from First import x`

Comment: Or from first import *

Comment: @Wimanicesir: From the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports): "Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `First.py`, you have defined two things: `x` and `a`.

When you run `from First import a` in `Second.py`, you explicitly stated that you want to import `a` and nothing else in the file.

Therefore, `x` cannot be accessed in `Second.py`, as it was not imported.

As mentioned in inspectorG4dget's comment, you could use `from First import x` as well, or you could do `from First import *` to import all defined values in `First.py`. There are other options as well, depending on your use case.